# Recursive delete of self-referential class

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a class called container. These containers act like a set of folders that can nest in a tree structure with an arbitrary number of children to an arbitrary depth. I would like to be able to delete these recursively when a parent folder is deleted.

I'm mostly looking if there is a way built-in to rails to do this and, if not, an efficient way. I've tried reading up on  `dependent: destroy`  but there is a warning in the rails docs that it may leave a database with orphans.

**container.rb**

```
class Container < ActiveRecord::Base

   belongs_to: parent,       #Reference to parent container
     class_name: "Container"
   has_many: children,       #Reference to children containers
     class_name: "Container", foreign_key: "parent_id"

end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want to destroy from the parent down (not from a child up) then you should add the `dependent: :destroy` to your `has_many` call (not the `belongs_to` which is where the orphan risk exists).

Comment: So I only have to worry about orphans with `belongs_to` in this case? Perfect. Thanks a ton!